# VBA Macro, type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get JSON data in excel and parse it. However, I'm getting an error: Type Mismatch.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is the link to the API I'm using: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub exceljson()

    Dim https As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer

    Set https = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    https.Open "GET", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD", False
    https.Send

    Set JSON = ParseJson(https.responseText)
    i = 2

    For Each Item In JSON
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("USD")
        i = i + 1
    Next

    MsgBox ("complete")

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the Type Mismatch?  Set Breakpoint (F9) on the https.open line and then Step through with F8 key.

Comment: fyi, i just added an S to the end of this: XMLHTTP --> XMLHTTPS; now the error says: Active X component cannot create object

Comment: Try `Debug.Print Item, JSON(Item)`

Comment: On _which line_ are each of these errors occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you confirm you have correctly imported `JsonConverter` module and `Dictionary` Class and refer to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, then the following code will work:

```
    Public Sub exceljson()
    Dim https As Object, Json As Object, i As Integer

    Dim Item As Variant

    Set https = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    https.Open "GET", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD", False
    https.Send

    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(https.responseText)

    i = 2
    For Each Item In Json.Items
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item
        i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

---

### updated

You should analyze the Json data responsed by the sever, the value of "Data" is a Dictionary. So you should use a Dictionary in `For Each Loop`.

The following codes will get all the data, I just use the "high" key as example. You can easily output other keys into excel.

```
Public Sub exceljson()
    Dim https As Object, Json As Object, DataItem As Dictionary, i As Integer


    Set https = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    https.Open "GET", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG", False
    https.Send

    'Use this debug command to see the whole response text
    'Debug.Print https.responseText
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(https.responseText)


    i = 2
    For Each DataItem In Json("Data")
        'Use "high" as example, you can output other key/values
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = DataItem("high")

        i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Phil, this was perfect. It worked. But can you explain the logic of it? I'm trying to apply it the following URL except its giving me the first line but i'm trying to get specific values only. https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG

Comment: Thanks Phil. Instead of defining my URL in the code, how can I ask it to look through a range of URLs in Sheet2 and grab the data through it?

Comment: As you can see, each URL may require you to look into the Json struct, so I think you have to do it one by one. You may need several Sub procedures to do that.
To get input from sheet2 is pretty easy in VBA, I think you can do it.